# Prepopulate info from database

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, intel-xdk, mobile-application, kinvey, mbaas

I'm on a project trying to build a mobile app using Kinvey and Intel XDK (using Bootstrap). The app we are building is basically an inventory management app and we are inquiring about the populating of info from the DB. So when the app calls the back end and you choose, for example, a room in the building. Then the field below it will auto populate with the boxes that are only in that room. For a function like that to work, would you need to build your UI to work that way or would you need a function to call Kiney to do that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You will simply populate that field with the result of a call like this: GET https://baas.kinvey.com/appdata/<your-api-key>/rooms/<selected-room-id>/boxes